Tabulator Sum of all groups
I am using tabulator to show my data State and City wise, grouping works fine but when added SUM of all groups, its only calculating of "CITY" only.
groupBy: ['State', 'City']
columnCalcs: "both",
Please let me know how to add sum of States too..
Thanks.
Laxmi Lal
